# Attempting to solve a linear program using Maxima, but problem unbounded.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-software

As the title says, I'm attempting to use Maxima's `minimize_lp(objective,conditions,nonegative=true)` to solve a linear program, where the function $z(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 10x_1 + 4x_2 + 5x_3$ is to be minimized with the conditions
\begin{align}
5x_1 - 7x_2 + 3x_3 &\geq 50,\\
x_1,x_2,x_3 &\geq 0\,.
\end{align}
However, I'm getting the `Problem not bounded!` error as a result, and wondering what the cause of this is. Surely the problem is not unbounded? If it is, is it possible to see it right from the start? I'm really rusty on matrix algebra and have't actually taken a course in optimization methods, so I have no idea what to look for here.

Comment: Is this $$x_1$$ in your second line?

Comment: Yes, let me fix that.

Comment: The problem is not unbounded. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+10x+%2B+4y+%2B+5z,+5x+-+7y%2B+3z+%3E+50,+x%3E+0,+y%3E+0,+z%3E+0) Have you tried to solve the problem with the simplex method?

Comment: it is immediate that the objective value cannot drop below 0

Comment: I think the reason is a typo in the statement. `minimize_lp(10*x1+4*x2+5*x3,[5*x1−7*x2+3*x3>=50,x1>=0,x2>=0,x3≥0]);` will work but `minimize_lp(10*x1+4*x2+5*x3,[5*x1−7*x2+3*x3>=50,x>=0,x2>=0,x3≥0]);` will raise this error because `x1` is not bounded now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'code' for Maxima is

[image]

It confirms what I´ve calculated with the Simplex method and [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+10x+%2B+4y+%2B+5z,+5x+-+7y%2B+3z+%3E+50,+x%3E+0,+y%3E+0,+z%3E+0).

Comment: Looks like I've once again failed to read the documentation properly. It was the `nonegative=true` inside the function that caused the issue.

Comment: It seems that this was the mistake.

Comment: Turns out there is also another issue, which is that I was trying to feed symbolic expressions to the function, which it didn't like. I would love it if there was a way to parse symbolic expressions back into Maxima code, but if that isn't possible, then I will have to settle for what I have.

Comment: I don´t get your question. What is now your problem? Haven´t it worked?

Comment: I added additional information to the original question. I might need to approach this problem in a completely different manner, since I'm generating random numbers while trying to come up with a random problem for students to solve.

Comment: I´ve  answered your questions. I took me some time to do so. Please mark the question as answered and ask a new question for your new problem.

Comment: Fair enough. I will do just that.